# Why doesn't glBlitNamedFramebuffer() work properly?

Tags: opengl

I am playing a bit with bit blitting in OpenGL. When I run the code looking like this:

```
GLuint fbo = CreateFBO(); // creates fbo and attaches a texture to it

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
GLfloat some_color[] = {0.8, 0.4, 0.6, 1.0};
glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 0, some_color);

glBlitNamedFramebuffer(0, fbo, 0, 0, 100, 100, 0, 0, 100, 100, GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, GL_NEAREST);

glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT |GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);

glBlitNamedFramebuffer(fbo, 0, 0, 0, 100, 100, 0, 0, 100, 100, GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, GL_NEAREST);
```

It yields a black screen, that is, the screen was cleared, although it should have the color of `some_color`. But if I change the "named" function to the "unnamed" counterpart, then it works as intended. The new piece of code looks like:

```
GLuint fbo = CreateFBO(); // creates fbo and attaches a texture to it

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
GLfloat some_color[] = {0.8, 0.4, 0.6, 1.0};
glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 0, some_color);

glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo_);
glBlitFramebuffer(0, 0, 100, 100, 0, 0, 100, 100, GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, GL_NEAREST);

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT |GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);

glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo_);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
glBlitFramebuffer(0, 0, 100, 100, 0, 0, 100, 100, GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, GL_NEAREST);
```

And executing this code, I get the expected result, namely the screen having the color of `some_color`. What am I doing wrong employing bit blitting? Or if I am using it correctly, why doesn't it work properly?

UPD: I mixed up blit functions in the second code sample.

Comment: For some reason, my DSA code perfectly worked on linux (nvidia proprietary) but on windows it doesn't. glBlitNamedFramebuffer can blit to window's backbuffer but not any else! I have to use non-dsa blit as a workaround.

Answer (score 3):

> It yields a black screen, that is, the screen was cleared, although it should have the color of some_color.

No it shouldn't. The first parameter to `glBlitNamedFramebuffer` is the *read* framebuffer. So your blit reads from the default framebuffer and writes to the FBO. You clear the screen. Then you reverse this operation. This copies from the FBO to the default framebuffer. Thus overwriting the clear.

Whatever it is you see on the screen, it should be anything *but* `some_color`.

Comment: I accidentally mixed up blit functions in the second sample, that is, I changed `glBlitNamedFramebuffer()` to `glBlitFramebuffer()`. And as I wrote in my quastion, the results of the code snippets are different. In the first case, the screen was cleared, and in the second one the screen has the color of `some_color`.

Comment: I still cannot understand your answer. So, the default framebuffer is first cleared with `some_color`, then we read from it and copy to the FBO, so FBO now also has `some_color`, then the default framebuffer is cleared with the default clear color (assume it's black), and finally, `some_color` in FBO gets copied back to the default framebuffer, overwriting the clear black. Since `some_color` overwrites the clear, why shouldn't we see it on the screen??